# Prove $S_k$ is a stopping based on $A$ being previsible

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

It looks like we have a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$ where

$A = \{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is an $\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$-adapted process which is previsible meaning it is $\{\mathscr F_{n-1}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ adapted.

To prove $S_k$ is a stopping time, we have to prove that

$$\{S_k = m\} \in \mathscr F_m \ \forall m \in \mathbb N$$

Now

$$\{S_k = m\} = \{\inf\{n \in \mathbb Z^{+} \ : \  A_{n+1} > k\}  = m\}$$

I'm guessing $$\{\inf\{n \in \mathbb Z^{+} \ : \  A_{n+1} > k\}  = m\} =$$

$$\bigcap_{n=0}^{m} \{A_n \le k\} \cap \{A_{m+1} > k\} \in \mathscr F_m$$

$$\because \bigcap_{n=0}^{m} \{A_n \le k\} \in \mathscr F_m \ \text{and} \ \{A_{m+1} > k\} \in \mathscr F_m$$

Is that right?

Also, how should I interpret $S_k$? The first time $A$ exceeds k plus 1?

Comment: $\{S(k)\le m\} = \{A_{m+1}>k\}\in\mathscr F_{m}$, because $A$ is previsible.

Comment: @JohnDawkins oh had a typo there. I like yours better hahaha. Post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{S(k)\le m\} =\{A_{m+1}>k\}\in\mathscr F_m$, because $A$ is previsible.

Comment: Actually, I think $$\{ S(k) \le m \} = \bigcup_{p=2}^{m+1} \{A_{p} > k\}$$ ?

Comment: Because $A$ is non-decreasing, the events in your union are nested, and the union is the same as $\{A_{m+1}>k\}$.